# How do I give a value to my checkbox in java so for example, "when checkbox is selected = add + £20 total"?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
Fruitslbl = new JLabel();
getContentPane().add(Fruitslbl, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
Fruitslbl.setText("Fruits");
```

I'm totally new to Java. I'm using GUI builder and using Eclipse.

Comment: You should also have some code that refers to a checkbox if your question concerns checkboxes. Also, before posting, you can often answer your own question with a quick internet search, which would unearth nuggets like [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jcheckbox-basic-tutorial-and-examples).

Comment: I tried to google it, it made no sense to me I found this, and also I added my code in a wrap check, I found this my code is different to this  Checkbox c = new Checkbox("Pepperoni"));
  add(c);
add(new Checkbox("Pepperoni"));

add(new Checkbox("Pepperoni", null, true));


  private void handleCheckbox(Checkbox c) {
  
    if (c.getState()) price += 0.50;
    else price -= 0.50;

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a buttonhandler for your JCheckbox and then you add your new JButton to the button handler then you will add a actionListener, ill give you an example i have for a GUI that has a JButton, essential the same thing. then in your ButtonHandler make it change all the values you want code with an example for this will also be below

```
public class GameBoard extends JFrame{

private static final Color red = new Color(200,55,55);
private static final Color blue = new Color(55,55,200);
private static final Color green = new Color(55,220,55);
private static final int SIZE = 10;
static JButton[][] tiles;
private static boolean cpTurn = false;



public static void main(String[] args){

    tiles = new JButton[SIZE][SIZE];
    JLabel label = new JLabel();


    GameBoard gb = new GameBoard();
    JButton refreashButton = new JButton("Refreash");
    ButtonHandler listener = new ButtonHandler();
    refreashButton.addActionListener(listener);
    refreashButton.setName("refreash");

    JPanel mineField = new JPanel();
    mineField.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
    mineField.setSize(500,500);

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            tiles[i][j] = new JButton();
            tiles[i][j].setSize(50,50);
            tiles[i][j].setVisible(true);
            tiles[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);
            tiles[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            tiles[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            tiles[i][j].setBackground(green);//green
            tiles[i][j].addActionListener(listener);
            tiles[i][j].setName(i+""+j);
            mineField.add(tiles[i][j]);
        }
    }
    JPanel board = new JPanel();
    board.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    board.add(mineField);
    board.add(refreashButton);
    board.setBackground(green);*/


    JPanel board = new JPanel();
    board.setLayout(new BoxLayout(board, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    board.add(mineField);
    board.add(refreashButton);



    JFrame window = new JFrame("BoardGame");
    window.setContentPane(board);
    window.setSize(600,700);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();

        if(cpTurn == false){
            if(btn.getName().equals("refreash")){
                cpTurn = false;
            }
            else{
                cpTurn = true;
                }
        } 
        else {
            cpTurn = false;
        }

        if(btn.getName().equals("refreash")){
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++){
                for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
                tiles[i][j].setBackground(green);
                }
            }
        }

        else if(btn.getBackground().equals(green)){
            btn.setBackground(red);
        }
        else if(btn.getBackground().equals(red)){
            btn.setBackground(blue);
            String name = btn.getName();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(0,1));
            int y = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(1));

            if(x - 1 >= 0 && tiles[x-1][y].getBackground().equals(red) ){
                tiles[x-1][y].setBackground(blue);
            }
            if(x + 1 <= 9 && tiles[x+1][y].getBackground().equals(red) ){
                tiles[x+1][y].setBackground(blue);
            }
            if(y + 1 <= 9 && tiles[x][y+1].getBackground().equals(red)){
                tiles[x][y+1].setBackground(blue);
            }
            if(y - 1 >= 0 && tiles[x][y-1].getBackground().equals(red)){
                tiles[x][y-1].setBackground(blue);
            }
        }
        else if(btn.getBackground().equals(blue)){
            btn.setBackground(green);
        }


        if(cpTurn){
        int randx = (int)(Math.random() *(10));
        int randy = (int)(Math.random() *(10));
        tiles[randx][randy].doClick();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm so sorry to bother you I'm lost I used GUI builder in eclipse so all my code structure looks different which confuses me when I look at yours, I do have buttons, I have 1 that updates total price I also have another to proceed to next page for checkout. What do you think of this, I just made this "private void handleCheckbox(Checkbox Strawberrychk) {
    
      if (Strawberrychk.getState()) TotalPrice += 1.50;
      else TotalPrice -= 1.50;
    
    }
}
"

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [JCheckbox - ActionListener and ItemListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882845/jcheckbox-actionlistener-and-itemlistener) 
You have to define action listener for your checkbox and put your actions inside listener code.