# Java - setVisible only works after clicking on screen

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, jframe, jcheckbox

I have a jframe with a jcheckbox and a jtextfield (it has many more components).

I set the label to setVisible(false) and when the checkbox is checked, it should turn the label visible. It actually does, but you just can´t see it until you click anywhere else on the frame.

Here is some of the code:

```
jTextField17 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
jTextField17.setText("Quantas?");
jTextField17.setVisible(false);
jTextField17.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(52, 20));


jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
jCheckBox1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 153));
jCheckBox1.setText("Cabecinhas");
jCheckBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
   }
});


private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
        jTextField17.setVisible(true);
    }else{
        jTextField17.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

I don´t think there´s anything wrong with the code.

To sum up:

user clicks checkbox. checkbox gets marked, nothing else seems to happen. user clicks anywhere on screen (after checking checkbox) and the textfield appears.

I´m using netbeans GUI editor. I would like to show the whole code, but it´s 3000+ lines. If you need to see more, ask me what part you need and I´ll edit here. Thanks for reading this and thank you even more for trying to help.

Comment: I now believe the problem is on the code generated by netbeans. I made another frame from scratch without GUI and it works as it should. Has anyone ever come across this problem on netbeans IDE?

Comment: I use netbeans to, it's not netbeans it's your code. I placed an answer down below of adding one line. Try it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882845/jcheckbox-actionlistener-and-itemlistener  Nice link describes the difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `this.repaint();` and `this.revalidate();`

```
private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
        jTextField17.setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();

    }else{
        jTextField17.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Do you know why this happened? Although many people are just looking for a piece of code, I´m trying to understand java.

Comment: If it worked could you please accept my answer ? so others also could benefit of that!

Comment: @DrNetwork repaint() method  causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible  Otherwise, this method causes a call to this component's update method as soon as possible. update(Graphics g) method of Component calls this component's paint method to redraw this component.   Its like refreshing the screen..as I think!

Comment: @DrNetwork for further reference use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to repaint it make it, otherwise it waits until it is repainted.

```
private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
        jTextField17.setVisible(true);
        jTextField17.repaint();
    }else{
        jTextField17.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will not initially set the textfield's setVisible method to false, you may do away with this issue.